# Which L-functions are not "Langlands-Shahidi L-functions"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

The Langlands-Shahidi method, among other things, obtains certain L-functions from the constant term of Eisenstein series attached to so-called $(G,M)$ pairs, where $G$ is a reductive group, $M$ a Levi subgroup, $N$ the unipotent radical. Particularly, these L-functions are given by the adjoint representation of the dual $^LM$ on the Lie algebra of $^LN$. Among the L-functions that arise are certain standard, symmetric power, exterior power, and Rankin-Selberg L-functions.

It is known that the list of L-functions obtained by this method does not give all the L-functions of interest, for example the spin L-function of quasi-split D4, studied by Hundley and Gan.

The question is the following: which L-functions do not arise from the Langlands-Shahidi method? Are they able to be characterized?

Comment: Where did you find the list? If the list is complete, then anything else is not from Langlands-Shahidi method.

Comment: My list comes from Kim's notes in the Fields lecture notes on Automorphic L-Functions. The list is long but I am not certain that it is complete.

Comment: Can you give a link or reference of Kim's notes?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1As2UzS pp. 143, 144

Comment: If you want examples of l functions which were studied by integral representation method but are not covered by Langlands shahidi method, you probably can google David Ginzburg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complete list is in Shahidi's book: Eisenstein Series and Automorphic $L$-Functions,
Colloquium Publications, Vol. 58, American Math. Society, 2010.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!

Comment: Thank you, Professor Shahidi!

Answer (score 1):

The most complete list I could find of L-functions accessible by the Langlands-Shahidi method (for split groups only) is found in the monograph [Lectures on Automorphic L-functions](https://books.google.com/books?id=jb3ZCp0-MQsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=143&f=false).

EDIT: Henry Kim has a paper in which "The purpose of this paper is three-fold; first, to make it explicit **all L-functions which appear in the constant term of the Eisenstein series** by combining the list in [La] and [Sh3]..", titled [On local L-functions and normalized intertwining operators](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-2005-023-x).

Comment: This isn't really an answer, so it should probably have been a comment or an edit to the question.

Comment: I happened to be thinking about this question again, and @DavidLoeffler's comment is totally accurate, so I am unaccepting that answer of mine, which indeed should have been a comment.